# Get latest version based on Id and date in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have an array of javascript objects containing the following properties: `_id, isVersionFrom, createdAt`
`_id, isVersionFrom` have an mongoDb _id stored (isVersionFrom is false when it is the original object). `createdAt` has a timestamp from epoch.
Now I would like to get an array with the latest version for each `_id`.

So for example if I have this array:

`[
  {
    _id: 'CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg',
    createdAt: 1493630867411,
    isVersionFrom: false
  },
  {
    _id: 'nnFthaqJ254BQozSp',
    createdAt: 1493630967411,
    isVersionFrom: 'CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg'
  },
  {
    _id: 'Jksfe6Aaof9hT8CW9',
    createdAt: 1493631067411,
    isVersionFrom: 'CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg'
  },
  {
    _id: 'HSitgQdFwYHqCjRax',
    createdAt: 1493631067411,
    isVersionFrom: false
  },
  {
    _id: 'vhZZCKhyQgkNSGjqK',
    createdAt: 1493631077411,
    isVersionFrom: 'HSitgQdFwYHqCjRax'
  },
]`

I would like this result:

`[
  {
    _id: 'Jksfe6Aaof9hT8CW9',
    createdAt: 1493631067411,
    isVersionFrom: 'CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg'
  },
  {
    _id: 'vhZZCKhyQgkNSGjqK',
    createdAt: 1493631077411,
    isVersionFrom: 'HSitgQdFwYHqCjRax'
  },
]`

So it basically has to filters out all older versions of an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Possible solution using Underscore:

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    _id: "CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg",
    createdAt: 1493630867411,
    isVersionFrom: false
  },
  {
    _id: "nnFthaqJ254BQozSp",
    createdAt: 1493630967411,
    isVersionFrom: "CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg"
  },
  {
    _id: "Jksfe6Aaof9hT8CW9",
    createdAt: 1493631067411,
    isVersionFrom: "CXsqvJ3ArwpM7aQwg"
  },
  {
    _id: "HSitgQdFwYHqCjRax",
    createdAt: 1493631067411,
    isVersionFrom: false
  },
  {
    _id: "vhZZCKhyQgkNSGjqK",
    createdAt: 1493631077411,
    isVersionFrom: "HSitgQdFwYHqCjRax"
  }
];

// Chain underscore methods to use seamlessly.
const result = _.chain(myArray)
  // Group items either by isVersionFrom or by original _id.
  .groupBy(item => (!item.isVersionFrom ? item._id : item.isVersionFrom))
  // For each group take item with max date (latest) .
  .map(val => _.max(val, item => item.createdAt))
  // Get value of chain.
  .value();
```

Comment: Hey Ramil, great suggestion. Only thing is that when isVersionFrom is false and there are no other versions in the array I still need that isVersionFrom false object as the object is the original.

Comment: @JoeriSmits does it mean that if there is some element with string value inside `isVersionFrom` there is also an element with the equal `_id` and `isVersionFrom: false`?

Comment: That is true, The objects are files and the first file uploaded has ```isVersionFrom: false``` all next files uploaded on top of this file have ```isVersionFrom: id of original file```

Comment: Thank you. I already wrote a solution based on your first version, but your updated solution is much cleaner. I really should learn underscore :).